# Merge two page type in SilverStripe

Tags: silverstripe

```
$page1 = PageType1::get();
$page2 = PageType2::get();
```

Is there any way in to fetch latest 5 post from combination of two page type.
Any help is accepted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `PageType1` and `PageType2` are both children of `Page` class you can do:

```
$myPages = Page::get()->filter(['ClassName' => ['PageType1', 'PageType2']]);
```

or any other parent class of both page types.

You can sort by Date created (which is saved in SiteTree table), and limit, e.g.

```
$sortedAndLimited = $myPages->sort('Created')->limit(5);
```

Downside: you cannot easily search, filter or sort for individual fields that are not shared with the parent class `Page`, for doing this you need to make the joins manually.